# $ C^1(\bar \Omega) \subseteq C^\alpha (\bar \Omega) $ holds for $ \Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 $ with $ \partial \Omega $ Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions, holder-spaces

For $ \alpha \in (0,1) $,
$$ 
C^1(\bar \Omega) \subseteq  C^\alpha (\bar \Omega) 
$$
holds for $ \Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 $ with $ \partial \Omega $ Lipschitz?
Could anyone recommend some reference?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: i think this holds regardless of boundary conditions

Comment: @ Calvin Khor See Gilbarg-Trudinger Page 53 for counterexample.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the counterexample

Comment: See Hans-Wilhelm Alt: Linear Functional Analysis, Section 10.6. https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781447172796

Comment: @  PhoemueX Thank you for the reference!